# Can not compile this small oracle 10g database function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, syntax-error

While experimenting on oracle 10g R2 following code does not work or I don't know how to do it.

I am anticipating rows from this function to be returned from `STUDENTS` table when I pass id .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OCT.GET_Student(ID_IN NUMBER) RETURN OCT.STUDENTS%ROWTYPE
IS
TYPE REC OCT.STUDENTS%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO REC FROM OCT.STUDENTS WHERE STUD_ID=ID_IN
EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERR'||SQLCODE);
END;
```

expected output will be one or two rows from the database table.
right now I am not able to compile this function .

errors returned

```
FUNCTION OCT.GET_STUDENT
On line:  3
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "OCT" when expecting one of the following:

   ( array limited new private range record VARRAY_ char_base
   number_base decimal date_base clob_base blob_base bfile_base
   table ref object fixed varying opaque sparse
The symbol "range" was substituted for "OCT" to continue.
```

**note** I do have proper rights on table and schema and function is created but with errors.

Plz help me understand what's wrong here.

Comment: Is the "IS" meant to be a DECLARE? Also when declaring the variables you want variablename type(size). This is just a shot in the dark, I've never seen % where you are placing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION OCT.GET_Student(ID_IN NUMBER) RETURN OCT.STUDENTS%ROWTYPE
IS
   REC OCT.STUDENTS%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
     SELECT * INTO REC FROM OCT.STUDENTS WHERE BCODE=ID_IN;
     RETURN(REC); --- A FUNCTION SHOULD RETURN SOMTHING.
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERR'||SQLCODE);
     RETURN(NULL); --- A FUNCTION SHOULD RETURN SOMTHING.
END;
```

While defining variable using `ROWTYPE` , we need not specify keyword `TYPE`.. Because it is already TYPE implicitly!